# error in postman req.body() is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i am importing an data from mongodb to get it in backend so iwrite a post reqest as follows-

```
app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
const body = req.body();
Data.save(body)
.then(response => {
  console.log('saved to mongo db', response);
  res.json(response);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('error in saving to mongo db', error);
  res.json(error);
});
});
```

but i am getting an error in postman that req.body() is not a function
can anybody please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `()` from `req.body()`. ==> `const body = req.body`.

Comment: showing same that aslo

Comment: Have you added these lines after const app = express();

`app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
`